# Music Production Tools (DJ)

Tags: sound, wine, productivity

I just switched to Ubuntu 12.04 from Windows 8.1 and I really like it. Although it requires getting used to some different things, nothing in my normal routine that I do has been affected by the switch. Except for one thing.

I dj and make my own tracks. I have 2 mixers I used on Windows and haven't found any *dj* type programs for Ubuntu. And they aren't listed on *Wine*. Is there any work around? I use *Djuced* and *Mixmeister Pro*.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found your favorite programs in WineDB, just try to start them anyway. Chances are, they will start and maybe even work. Don't forget to write a WineDB entry afterwards.
Although, here's MixMeister's entry:
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1183